# Activity to trigger and cancel a AlarmManager

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I am trying to develop an app where it locks down the `Activity` and starts a service which will set an `AlarmManager` to `setRepeating()` trigger to another `Service` which will send a SMS containing the phone's location.

I have achieved the periodic sending of the SMS. However, I now want to cancel the `AlarmManager` when I `finish()` the lockdown activity. Please help me as I cant seem to understand the approach to address this.

Program flow:
Lockscreen (Activity trigger Service) --> AlarmManager (in Service class) --> Coordinate (Another Service that send sms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` with an equivalent `PendingIntent` to the one you used to register the alarm in the first place. By "equivalent" I mean that it is the same type of `PendingIntent` (activity, service, broadcast) and wraps an `Intent` that is the same on all routing elements (component, data, MIME type, categories).